# How can I bring back my lost folder?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have an external HDD. I moved my `C:\Users\MyUser\Videos` folder to my HDD. Today I tried to rename a folder in Video folder then I found out that the hard is not listed in `Computer` so I detached it and attached it again and I saw a renamed folder that was unreachable (and the old folder wasn't there). Then I refresh the Video folder and the renamed folder was disappeared too.

How can I bring the old folder back?

I'm using Windows 8.1 that is not updated to the latest updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this command in cmd: `chkdsk e: /r` (assuming that e is your drive letter listed in your 'My Computer').
If you are note able to recover it then try file recovery programs like the one mentioned by Dark_Cyber in the previous Answer.

Comment: Youre welcome! @ahmadali shafiee

Answer (score 1):

Is the folder you're looking for in your EXT HDD? If so, why don't you copy it over to the desired location? If it's no longer on your EXT HDD, you might have accidentally deleted it. If so, try using a tool called "Recuva". I've had success with recovering accidentally deleted folders/files/etc in the past.

Comment: The folder is in Ext HDD but I think somehow I deleted it from partition table (I think this was the name of the place that the pointers are stored there)

Comment: The folder's name was `Television Series` and now I can't create a new folder with this name.

Comment: Try using a tool named "WinDirStat", it gives you a graphical representation of your directory structure, what's eating up your size, and it will display your directories in an Active Directory-esq view. If the folder exists you might be able to see where it's exact location is. 

Also, make sure you have "show hidden folders/files" enabled.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it later (after the `chkdsk ` operation finished) but I'm sure I didn't press the delete button (if I did the folder was in recycle bin!). I tried to rename it and it just disappeared. It's more than a hidden folder.